# Lombok annotations vs code coverage in Cobertura or similar tool

Tags: java, unit-testing, cobertura, lombok

[Configure cobertura to ignore certain blocks of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527734/configure-cobertura-to-ignore-certain-blocks-of-code)

From what I have read from above question, there's no way in Cobertura to exclude given code part from being tested versus having coverage in tests.

Is that true? /  Is it possible in any simmilar tool?

I'm usuing **Lombok** annotations `@Getter`, `@Setter` and so on, which are great, but **they result in being 'red' in coverage report, even if I'm testing getter and setter methods.** - I would like to do something with that... Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Isn't it possible to first run [delombok](http://projectlombok.org/features/delombok.html) over the code under test, compile it and then instrument it by [Cobertura](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/)?

Disclosure: I am one of the Project Lombok developers

Comment: How would this help? Delombok doesn't get rid of the getters/setters, which are still shown "red" in coverage.

Comment: Also in my case, some test code require generated `hashcode` and `equals` methods to work correctly. With delomboked code, the tests would break.

Comment: Why would the tests break on equals and hashCode? Is there something wrong with the generated code?

Answer (score 4):

Lombok adds a `@javax.annotation.Generated` annotation (1). But this annotation has `source` retention, i.e. your coverage tool can't see it any more :-(

Lombok 1.16.14 just fixed [issue-1014](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1014) by adding an option to generate a `@lombok.Generated` annotation instead; just configure `lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation`(2).

Cobertura can be configured to skip methods with some annotation, so most of the generated code won't count against your coverage.

JaCoCo doesn't provide a configuration mechanism to skip on certain annotations. [Issue-15](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/15) tries to fix this (and much more) without requiring any configuration.

(1) If not disabled with `lombok.addGeneratedAnnotation` which is now deprecated and should be replaced with `lombok.addJavaxGeneratedAnnotation`

(2) see [lombok config](https://projectlombok.org/features/configuration.html)

(3) see [this comment](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1014#issuecomment-270854270)

Answer (score 0):

Lombok creates additional code that has branches for certain methods. If, for example, you add @Data and your object does not 
override equals, you'll get a bunch of branches in the equals method for whether each of your member variables is null or not. 
So if you want to use Lombok, you'll just have to accept the lower branch counts or figure out some consistent way to have 
cobertura not count autogenerated code.

You can use Delombok to get a better idea of why the coverage is lower, but you won't be able to raise it without 
testing those branches that were autogenerated.

An earlier version of Lombok (0.12) interacted with cobertura in such a way that lombok generated code was not counted in coverage.

Another thing you could add is the 'ignoreTrivial' flag in Cobertura. This should take care of auto-generated getters and 
setters, but not things like equals() or hashCode().

To get coverage on equals() and hashCode() you can use [EqualsVerifier](https://jqno.nl/equalsverifier/).